Hypothesis and theory
Would the following definitions be correct?

Hypothesis is a proposition derived strictly by logic from the other, previously accepted as true, propositions.

Theory is an empirically proven hypothesis. Or an explanation why it hasn't been proven.



Theories needn't be confirmed by empirical means.  Math theories are still theories.

@JD Don't you think the word theory means something different in mathematics than in the other sciences?

A proposition derived strictly by logic from the other, previously accepted as true, propositions is called theorem, not hypothesis. Hypotheses are propositions that either surmise or explain what has been observed and they are 'derived' in all sorts of creative ways that often have nothing to do with logic. From intuitions, metaphors, analogies, philosophical musings, etc., whatever works. Logic is not particularly suited for making discoveries, it helps with analyzing and confirming them after the fact.

Why is this a philosophy question? Surely any dictionary provides the answer.

see my answer in this question - https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/why-arent-creationism-and-natural-science-on-the-same-intellectual-level/21607#21607

No, a hypothesis doesn't derive strictly from logic. Hypotheses are often made when new phenomena are discovered that do not corroborate with the existing theory.
Theory has many meanings but in general it is a well established explanation that is supported by evidence. Theories consist in general of a (large) set of hypotheses that are mutually in accordance. Some hypotheses are accepted within a theory but if that theory fails in light of new experimentation, then all the hypotheses that make up that theory are either false or subject to renewed scrutiny.
Phlogiston, for example, was a hypothetical substance in early theories of combustion. When those theories were replaced by Antoine Lavoisier's theory that explained combustion with oxygen, phlogiston was disproven.
The word theory is central to the philosophy of science and has sometimes a different meaning in common parlance.

ad 1: Conclusion is a proposition logically derived from other propositions. - A hypothesis is a premiss, not a conclusion.
ad 2: Accepted general theories in science are confirmed hypotheses. - Empiricism cannot prove general theories, only confirm or refute them.

Typo, I think: Premise.

@keshlam Premiss is a correct form but mostly British English and a bit archaic. You'll see it used in older philosophical articles.  This is why it probably doesn't show up in a spelling checker.

Ah. "Two nations divided by our common language." I wonder if Mike Cowlishaw's UK/US translating dictionary is on the internet anywhere.
